# VS2015 Log Truncated in test runner output

Tags: visual-studio-2015

In the test runner that comes with Visual Studio you can do a number of Console.WriteLine statements in you test method and those messages will be written to the Output window of the test.  I've used that extensively in VS2013.  Unfortunately in VS2015 I only see a little over a page of text in the test's Output before I see the message

> !!! LOG TRUNCATED !!! To get complete log, Select 'Copy All' on the
>   Right Click Menu and then paste into some text editor like notepad".

The message is very clear what VS2015 is doing and how to workaround this.  However, my question is how to I turn this "feature" off or at least increase the buffer size?

Comment: After no answers, I tried contacting the VS team by creating a User Voice issue.  You can up-vote it here: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/9719772-allow-to-turn-off-the-log-truncated-feature-of-the

Comment: +3 votes for you at visualstudio uservoice...

Comment: It seems to be limited to 5000 characters; this is a strange limitation. I hate to be "that guy" but if even Notepad is beating out Visual Studio's ability to read text there's something wrong here. I don't understand why they decided to allocate a fixed size buffer for this at all -- was Test Explorer just rushed out?

Comment: Now VS2019 and we still have this problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This had been fixed in a preview.  However, later on the fix was rolled the back.

If you update to the latest version of Visual Studio 2017, truncated test output is still a limitation.

Unfortunately, this is not simple to track as Microsoft uses multiple tools to track visual studio development.

You can track a user voice story here requesting the feature:

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/9719772-allow-to-turn-off-the-log-truncated-feature-of-the

Or, alternatively an open issue against visual studio here:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/57030/user-voice-story-on-truncating-test-log-output-was.html